# Load a class dynamically which is not in a folder in java

Tags: java, urlclassloader

I want to load a class dynamically which is not in a jar file but in a folder called Dinamics. Here is my code

```
URL urlOfClass=new File("Dinamics/").toURI().toURL();
URL[] classUrl=new URL[]{urlOfClass};
System.err.println(urlOfClass);
Class myClass=new URLClassLoader(classUrl).loadClass(command1);
myClass.getDeclaredConstructor(String.class).newInstance(command2);
```

This is the printed urlOfClass

```
......ha/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Project2.0/Dinamics/
```

And I get this error message

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MyClassName
```

What did I do wrong here?

Comment: What would be the value of urlOfClass, command1 and command2? and wihch specific line throw the error message?

Comment: Command1 is "MyClassName" and Command2 is "Hello"

Comment: So does 'MyClassName' class really exist?

Comment: Yes there's a working class MyClassName.class in the folder Dinamics

Comment: @Maan Make sure MyClassName is in default package, otherwise you must specify it's `fully.qualified.MyClassName`.

Comment: @Lukas It is in the default class. By the way I didn't know that. Thank u.